# Run pwd command before running any command

Tags: linux, shell

I have work multiple directory location and sometime delete directory which should not be deleted.

Is it possible to run pwd command before execute any command. and if I remove any file should I have warning or any message info

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585397/bash-run-some-command-before-or-after-every-command-entered-from-console

Answer (score 1):

To receive warning use `-i` option of `rm`:

```
$ rm -i test.file
```

Instead of running `pwd` before any command just put current directory path into your prompt. Add `\w` to `$PS1` wariable. For example set it like this:

```
PS1="[\w]\$ "
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, is to create an alias like this:

```
alias rm="pwd; /bin/rm -rfi"
```

With '-i' option you have to confirm the removing.

If you want that alias is loaded on startup you can add on the bottom of file:

```
~/.bashrc
```