# Select random value from array before every prompt in bash

Tags: bash, prompt, tput

I'm trying to make a custom prompt that selects one random value from the following lists:

```
color=(1 2 3 4 5 6)
much=(such very much many so)
wow=(wow hacker terminal geek confusion)
```

then does this before every prompt.

```
tput setaf $rcolor
echo -n "$rmuch $rwow $ "
```

The problem is, if I use `PS1`, it executes on terminal startup and doesn't update before every prompt.
How do I get a different, random message before every prompt?

Sample output:

```
such hacker $
much wow $
very geek $
such wow $
much confusion $
very terminal $
```

Comment: Almost a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585397/bash-run-some-command-before-or-after-every-command-entered-from-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `$`:

```
PS1="\$(tput setaf \${color[\$RANDOM%6]})\${much[\$RANDOM%5]} \${wow[\$RANDOM%5]}: "
```

`PS1` is evaluated every time is printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trap` as well:

```
much=(such very much many so)
wow=(wow hacker terminal geek confusion)
max=${#much[@]}
trap 'PS1="${much[$((RANDOM % max))]} ${wow[$((RANDOM % max))]} $ "' DEBUG
```

**Output:**

```
much confusion $
such terminal $
such confusion $
such geek $
so terminal $
very confusion $
such geek $
such terminal $
much terminal $
many geek $
```