# How can i automatically log the shell history each time a command is typed?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple script that writes the shell history to a txt file. But I need to overwrite that file each time a user types a new command. Any ideas?

```
 #! /bin/bash

 history > /tmp/shell_history_$USER.text
```

Comment: show your "simple script"

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585397/how-to-run-some-command-before-or-after-every-bash-command-entered-from-console) and its answers might help you.